# Top align characters

Tags: vertical-alignment

I wonder if there's a good way to vertically align the tops of characters.

I'm trying to reproduce a particular style of the No. symbol which has an N with an ọ next to it (that's an o with a dot below). The top of the o and the top of the N should be level.

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newlength{\nheigh}
\settoheight{\nheigh}{N}

\begin{document}

N\raisebox{\nheigh}{\d{o}}

\end{document}
```

But of course this aligns the bottom of the o with the top of the N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let TeX do the computations; for such jobs, lower level primitives are more flexible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fancyno}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{N}%
  N\vbox to\ht0{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr o\cr\noalign{\vfill}.\cr}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\fancyno \quad {\LARGE\fancyno}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the period to sit on the baseline, no measuring is necessary, under the assumption that `\d{o}` has total vertical size less than `N`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fancyno}{%
  \begingroup\tabskip 0pt % just for safety
  \valign{##\vfill\cr\hbox{N}\cr\hbox{\d{o}}\cr}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\fancyno \quad {\LARGE\fancyno}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Good start. The height of the `o` needs to be subtracted from the height of the `N` for the raise amount. The height of `o` is available as `\height` inside `\raisebox` and the calculation can be done with e-TeX's `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newlength{\nheigh}
\settoheight{\nheigh}{N}

\begin{document}

N\raisebox{\dimexpr\nheigh-\height\relax}{\d{o}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A macro can be defined that uses a local scratch register for measuring the height of the `N`. Then, the macro automatically adapts to the current size:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newcommand*{\No}{%
  \begingroup
    \settoheight{\dimen0}{N}%
    N\raisebox{\dimexpr\dimen0-\height\relax}{\d{o}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

{\Huge\No}{\huge\No}{\LARGE\No}{\Large\No}{\large\No}{\No}%
{\small\No}{\footnotesize\No}{\scriptsize\No}{\tiny\No}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with different sizes]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `\raisebox`, you can also stack `\vbox`es. For this `\lineskip` has to be zeroo to avoid unwanted space and `\lineskiplimit` must be big such that `\lineskip` is used in the first place. Then you can create a `\vtop` for every character which aligns at an empty box above the characters, sucht that the tops are aligned:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\topalign[1]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \providecommand\tachar[1]{\vtop{\null\hbox{##1}}}%
    \vbox{%
      \lineskip0pt%
      \lineskiplimit\maxdimen%
      \hbox{%
        #1%
      }%
      \null%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\topalign{\tachar{N}\tachar{\d{o}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

With this approach you do not have to know which character is the largest.